# How to get value on php page by jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jquery ajax script for getting the content of php page without loading of page. Using following script

```
$('#data_subpartition_result').live('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "temp/model_view_result.php",
           context: "language=php&version=5",
           data: {train: 0.7, validation: 0.2, test: 0.1},
           success: function(result){
                    $('div.divRightModelContent').html(result);
               }
    });
});
```

and my php file code is as follows

```
<?php 
     echo $_POST['train'];

     // some other php stuff

?>
```

i am trying to print or using value of data which i have passed with post method by jquery ajax call but i have an error and no any value passed in post method on php page by jquery ajax call. Give me any idea how to get the value.

Comment: unless it's a typo, you have an error closing the live function so at the end of your jquery code above add another `});`

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I programmed in PHP, but here are a few jQuery things to correct.

1. `context` is not used the way you're using it. It's used to tell the `$.ajax` call to load a particular section of the `url` property.
2. Because you specified `type: "POST"`, your `.html()` call should be: `('div.divRightModelContent').html(result.d)`.

There are some good examples on the official [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) webpage. They're pretty good about at least providing you with example data under each property.